# How to create a constructor that takes in two variables, yet one of them is optional. C++

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to create a constructor that takes in two variables, yet the program has to be able to create an object with only one variable. If the object being constructed is missing the second variable it must initialize it to zero.

```
constructor(int x, int y)
```

Example:

```
constructor a (5, 5)
constructor b(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple constructors for one class that have different signatures:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int x, y;
    Foo()               : x(0),  y(0)  {}
    Foo(int _x)         : x(_x), y(0)  {}
    Foo(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
}

Foo a(5);    // a.x == 5, a.y == 0
Foo b(5, 5); // b.x == 5, b.y == 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like regular functions, the parameters of a constructor can have a default value.  Using

```
constructor(int x, int y = 0) : x_var(x), y_var(y) {}
```

Allows you to call the constrcutor with either one or two parameters.  You can even use

```
constructor(int x = 0, int y = 0) : x_var(x), y_var(y) {}
```

which now lets you call the constructor with zero, one, or two parameters.